# get virtual machine information on Host

Tags: virtualization, qemu, libvirt

How to retrieve virtual machine data such as ip address on the HOST .

I've created virtual machines using `qemu-system-x86_64`.

Comment: You probably are looking for virsh, See the PDF doc or html here http://libvirt.org/virshcmdref.html - for your case you probably want to look at the `net-info` command. Btw you should 1. ask more details, describe what you tried to do, 2. tag with `qemu` and not python. Qemu and libvirt are not python specific afaik

Comment: how is virsh related to qemu-system-x86_64? I am not able to see the vm's deployed by `qemu-system-x86_64` when I try to list them using `virsh list`."

Answer (score 1):

At time of asking, it was not possible to query the guest IP address from virsh. Modern libvirt though supports the "domifaddr" command in virsh which lets you query the DHCP assigned IP address for guests that are connected to libvirt's "default" network. It does not work for guests using direct bridging to the LAN.

Second, there is now also the ability to setup an NSS module on the host, so you can login to guests based on their hostname, instead of raw IP. Again this works for guests using the default network